# Does there exist a differentiable metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: derivatives, metric-spaces

Suppose $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the function $$ f(x) = d(0,x).$$ My question is: Does there exist a function $f$ (equivalent to say the existence of a metric $d$) such that $f$ is differentiable with respect to the usual sense of differentiation on $\mathbb{R}$?

Any insight is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, $d(x, y) = \lvert x^3 - y^3 \rvert$ works, then $f(x) = \lvert x \rvert^3$.

I've used the cube power so that it's a metric on the entirety of $\mathbb R$; using $d(x, y) =  \vert x^2 - y^2 \vert$ would give that $d(1, -1) = 0$.

Comment: Good point on squares, cubes work better. +1